# How to install Opera Mini without internet connection?

Tags: opera-mini

I'd like to know how to install Opera Mini without internet connection, because I'm going to test an application in my tablet, but it needs a browser that support proxy configuration and I don't have wi-fi to install Opera Mini.

I already downloaded the apk, but to install Opera Mini it needs connection to download itself. There is anyway I can install it without internet connection on my tablet? There is a full apk? If you have can you post the link for download or upload by yourself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible.

In the [Opera Mini FAQ](http://www.opera.com/mobile/help/faq/), it says:

> You **must have** a compatible **phone with an Internet connection**. When you
>   download Opera Mini, you will be told if your phone is known to work.
>   To see if your handset can run Opera Mini, visit the list of supported
>   devices.

Comment: Besides, as the app always routes traffic via its own server to "mobilize" the content, it obviously cannot be used without Internet connection either. So what sense should it make to install it without a connection? ;)